# Xamarin Forms Manage Alarm Clock

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it posible to manage the alarm clock from Android and iOS with the same Xamarin Forms code?

I have seen that its possible with nativ code.

thanks!

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms allows developers to define behavior in platform-specific projects. DependencyService then finds the right platform implementation, allowing shared code to access the native functionality.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/

Comment: Is it also possible without the DependencyService?

Comment: In straight NetStd/PCL code, NO. (If someone has done the work already and published it, technical yes, but it does require native code)

Comment: The feature you're asking is native in nature, that means you'd have to create the behavior natively, and make it available to forms via `DependencyService`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Xamarin.Forms is essentially an [absraction layer over native code.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/)

You will be able to create a user interface that shared between each platform you target, but you will need to write your own abstraction of the native platform API(s) that you wish to consume to get the behavior that you desire. As stated above, you can utilise the [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to achieve this.